# How to do error handling with async/await without having to await

Tags: javascript, async-await

Take the following contrived example:

```
const housekeepingStuff = async function (data) {
    const result = await notImportant(data);
    result.more = 'yawn';
    storeInDatabase(result);
};

const getStuff = async function () {
    try {
        const data = await getData();
        data.extra = 'wow';
        housekeepingStuff(data); // <---- don't want to await... but need to for error catching
        return Promise.resolve(data);
    } catch (err) {
        return Promise.reject(err);
    }
};

try {
    const myData = await doSomeStuff();
    res.send(myData);
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.sendStatus(400);
}
```

I want to return the data from `getStuff ()` ASAP without waiting for `housekeepingStuff()` but if I don't await that function then I have an uncaught error.

I could call `housekeepingStuff()` outside the `getStuff()` function, after getting and sending the data to whoever wants it:

```
try {
    const myData = await doSomeStuff();
    res.send(myData);
    await housekeepingStuff(data); // <---- am awaiting but who cares because nothing follows
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.sendStatus(400);
}
```

But that doesn't seem right because I don't want to have to remember to call `housekeepingStuff()` every time I call `doSomeStuff()`... it should ideally be handled "internally".

What is the correct approach here?

Comment: Probably you missing **res.end();** after **res.send(myData);**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A promise (or async) function has 2 possible outcomes:

1. A successful outcome
2. An error outcome

To get either outcome, you must wait for it. You can't wait for 1 condition and not for the other, because the entire thing needs to execute so you can find out what the outcome was.

Otherwise you're really asking the javascript engine: Please predict for me if the function will fail, and if it does, await it.

The correct approach therefore is to just await it.

However, if you don't care about either successful or failed outcomes of this function, just call the function via another async function that eats all the errors:

```
async function doSomeStuffAndIgnoreError() {
   try {
     await doSomeStuff();
   } catch (e) {
     console.error(e);
   }
}
```